# Pointers in const object are changing after being passed into another objects constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants

My problem is that when I call userInputManager.m_w->execute(); on line 6, (using VC 2017) I get

```
Exception thrown: read access violation. userInputManager.m_w-> was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

I mean line 6 of this code here:

```
        1 Graphics graphics{ window };
        2 Camera camera{ graphics };
        3 const UserInputManager userInputManager{ window };
        4 userInputManager.m_w->execute();
        5 Game theGame{camera, userInputManager };
        6 userInputManager.m_w->execute();
        7 while(window.ProcessMessage() )
```

Notice that line 4 does not give me an exception even though it is the same call.  Something is happening in line 5, Game theGame constructor, which is changing my userInputManager and making line 6 (which is identical to line 4) give exception.

Notice that I have made userInputManager const in line 3.

Here is the code for theGame constructor:

```
Game::Game(Camera & camera, const UserInputManager & userInputManager)
    :
    m_camera{ camera },
    m_userInputManager{userInputManager}
{   
}
```

Notice that I am passing in userInputManager as a const reference and setting m_userInputManager to the userInputManager reference.

Here is the UserInputManager class

```
 class UserInputManager
{
public:
    UserInputManager(MainWindow & window)
    :
    m_window{window}
{
        LeftCommand a;
        m_a = &a;
        UpCommand w;
        m_w = &w;
        m_w->execute();
}

    MainWindow & m_window;

    Command * m_w = 0;
    Command * m_s = 0;
    Command * m_a = 0;
    Command * m_d = 0;

};
```

In this class I am attempting to implement the command design pattern as is outlined in this book: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/command.html.

In the constructor I am attempting to assign some commands to buttons. I assign LeftCommand to m_a and UpCommand to m_w. I then call  m_w->execute(); just as a test which always works.

Here are the classes for the Commands:

```
/* Represents game actions. Uses Command pattern */
class Command
{
public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class UpCommand : public Command
{
public:
    virtual void execute()
    {
        executionN++;
    }
    int executionN = 0;
};


class LeftCommand : public Command
{
public:
    virtual void execute()
    {
        executionN++;
    }
    int executionN = 0;
};

class NullCommand : public Command
{
public:
    virtual void execute() { }
};
```

Right now UpCommand and LeftCommand just increment a value in order to test the function call.

This is my first post on this site. I tried to search for answers to this but couldn't really figure out even what to search for.

Please let me know if my post could be improved or clarified.

Thank you.

EDIT 1 : I changed the local creation of LeftCommand a and UpCommand w and made them static objects of the UserInputManager class. Now everything works great. My problem was indeed related to the dangling pointers. But is my solution of making  themstatic objects the best way to fix this? I just thought of it randomly

Comment: Just fyi, both of those pointers (`m_w` and `m_a`) are dangling the moment that constructor returns. They no longer point to anything viable.

Comment: In `m_w = &w;` the object `w` is a local object. It ceases to exist after your constructor returns.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Why does the call to userInputManager.m_w->execute(); on line 4 directly after the creation of the userInputManager work if the object no longer exists? (line 4 of my first block of code).

Comment: Invoking on an invalid reference results in Undefined Behaviour. The really annoying thing about Undefined Behaviour is, being undefined, the results can be anything from looking like it worked to visibly failing and [everything in between.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73wMnU7xbwE)

Comment: @user4581301 Is there some way to ensure this never happens to me again? Like some sort of c++17 magical features.

Comment: In general, no. Need more information in order to ansewr for this specific case. In this specific case, I assume you're going through the-hell-that-is-pointers in order to remap keys at some later point? Is there a possibility of multiple instances of `UserInputManager`? If there are multiple `UserInputManager`, then your `static` solution may not work. All `UserInputManager`s will start with the same keys and mess with each other's data.